# ANTLR4: rule 'RULE' contains a closure with at least one alternative that can match an empty string

Tags: antlr4

I am writing a file parser with `ANTLR4`. The file can have a number of blocks, which all begin and end with a (BEGIN | END) keyword. Here is a very simple example:

```
grammar test;

BEGIN: 'BEGIN';
END:   'END';
HEADER:'HEADER';
BODY:  'BODY';

file: block+;
ID: [A-Za-z];
NUM: [0-9];

block:
   | BEGIN HEAD statement* END HEAD
   | BEGIN BODY statement* END BODY
   ;
statement: ID '=' NUM;
```

The error thats get thrown is `error(153): test.g4:8:0: rule file contains a closure with at least one alternative that can match an empty string`
, what I don't understand, since `file` has at least one empty block, with the begin-end style. Anyone sees what I am missing here?

Comment: `HEAD` is not defined by a lexer rule. Be sure to address all code generation warnings -- treat them as errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`block` can match the empty string because there's nothing between the colon and the first `|`. Then in `file`, you use `block+`. This causes the error because you're applying `+` to something that can match the empty string, which could lead to an infinite looo that doesn't consume any input.

To fix this problem, just remove the first `|` in `block`.